# AppleScript - array read from disk is empty

Tags: applescript

I have a script that starts like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFolder to (choose folder)    
    set theFile to POSIX path of ((theFolder as string) & "words.txt")
    set fileHandle to open for access theFile
    set nameArray to paragraphs of (read fileHandle for (get eof fileHandle) as «class utf8»)
    close access fileHandle
end tell
```

File `words.txt` is there and contains one word per line.
`theFile` is a valid path to words.txt, something like `/Users/myself/Desktop/folder/words.txt`.

`nameArray` comes empty.
Why?

If instead of letting the user choose the folder, I hardcode the path, like

```
set theFile to "/Users/myself/Desktop/folder/words.txt"
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need **Finder** as the necessary *commands* are just basic **AppleScript** *commands* and or are all a part of **Standard Additions**.

The following three lines, by themselves, will do what you are trying to do:

```applescript
set theFolder to (choose folder)
set theFile to POSIX path of ((theFolder as string) & "words.txt")
set nameArray to paragraphs of (read theFile as «class utf8»)
```

Something to keep in mind, if the last line in the *file* ends with a *line feed* then the last *item* in the *list* will be `""` and you can either account for this in your *code* as you use each *item* of the *list* or add the following *example* to remove it if it exists:

```applescript
if last item of nameArray is equal to "" then ¬
    set nameArray to items 1 thru -2 of nameArray
```